# Why does the DI Bitmap contain zero?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I am trying to create a page like window with horizontal and vertical scrolls. Users can zoom in the contents of the page, which works fine except until the contents exceed the boundary of the page.

I have been trying to fix that problem using memory device contexts and Win32 GDI functions with little to no success.

Here is the code that zooms in the page.

```
  //Check if the zoom button was pressed.
  if(tmpn3 == 1){

   //Get a device context for the window.
   tmphdc2 = GetDC(GLB_HWndMainDialog);

   //Get a memory device context.
   tmphdc3 = CreateCompatibleDC(tmphdc2);

   //Set the stretch Blt mode.
   SetStretchBltMode(tmphdc2, \
                     BLACKONWHITE);

   //Set the stretch Blt mode.
   SetStretchBltMode(tmphdc3, \
                     BLACKONWHITE);

   //Zoom in the page and copy the pixels
   //to the memory DC.
   StretchBlt(tmphdc3, \
              0, \
              0, \
              612, \
              900, \
              tmphdc2, \
              0, \
              0, \
              408, \
              600, \
              SRCCOPY);

   //Zoom in the page and copy the pixels
   //to the window page.
   StretchBlt(tmphdc2, \
              8, \
              100, \
              400, \
              500, \
              tmphdc2, \
              8, \
              100, \
              200, \
              250, \
              SRCCOPY);

   //Check if tmpbits is not NULL.
   if(tmpbits != NULL){

    //Free tmpbits.
    free(tmpbits);

   } //EndIf

   //Get the DI bitmap of the page's
   //client area. This bitmap starts
   //at the bottom-left corner of the
   //page and ends at the top-right
   //corner of the main dialog.
   GetDIBPage(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
              &tmpbits);
 
   //Check if tmpbits2 is NULL.
   if(tmpbits2 == NULL){

    //Allocate memory to tmpbits2.
    tmpbits2 = (void*)calloc((4 * 620 * 920), sizeof(char));

   } //EndIf

   //Get the DI Bits from tmphdc3.

   //Allocate memory to tmpbmpinfo.
   tmpbmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)calloc(1, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

   //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
   tmpbmphdr = &(tmpbmpinfo->bmiHeader);

   //Set the members of the bitmap info
   //header
   tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   tmpbmphdr->biWidth = 612;
   tmpbmphdr->biHeight = 900;
   tmpbmphdr->biPlanes = 1;
   tmpbmphdr->biBitCount = 32;
   tmpbmphdr->biCompression = BI_RGB;
   tmpbmphdr->biSizeImage = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biClrUsed = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biClrImportant = 0;

   //Create a compatible bitmap.
   tmphbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tmphdc3, \
                                       612, \
                                       900);

   //Copy the bits from the bitmap into
   //tmpbits2. This does not include the
   //bitmap header.
   GetDIBits(tmphdc3, \
             tmphbitmap, \
             0, \
             900, \
             tmpbits2, \
             tmpbmpinfo, \
             DIB_RGB_COLORS);

   //Release the device context.
   ReleaseDC(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
             tmphdc2);

   //Free variables
   DeleteObject(tmphbitmap);
   DeleteDC(tmphdc3);
   free(tmpbmpinfo);
```

According to the Windows Documentation, StretchBlt should copy the pixels from the source DC to the destination DC, so I did not use the SelectObject and BitBlt functions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You never selected a bitmap into `tmphdc3`, so the DC is empty. Copying pixels to an empty DC copies nothing.

Comment: Do I still need to use the BitBlt function or will StretchBlt work?

Comment: I did as you suggested Raymond. I selected a bitmap created with the CreateCompatibleBitmap function. Then I used the StretchDIBits function to zoom in the bitmap and copy the results to tmphdc3. Now when I re-build the program and run it, the page is completely white after pressing the zoom button and while scrolling up and down the page; not exactly the results I was looking for but its progressing.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that a memory DC takes on the characteristics of the bitmap you select into it.  When you use `CreateCompatibleBitmap` make sure you refer it to a real DC and not the fake one you just created.

Comment: I passed the tmphdc2 handle to that function. So I think I did it right. The only problem is to get the area of the bitmap that exceeds the boundary of the page after a zoom. Right now, tmpbits2 looks like it only contains white pixels.